# Searching my application published on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

There is the following strange problem: I've published some app on Google Play, for example "My Horse" (2 words in name). But if I search my app as "My Horse" I can't find it! If I use "myhorse" (as a single word) all is good. As I know I use "My Horse" in all settings in the developer's console and Android string resources. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `iOS` in `android` you have no control over the keywords, just make sure your app description contain the keywords and the Console Search engine will take care of everything magically.

If you recently submitted your app, then give it time, it will show in your search results.

Comment: Now my description doesn't contain name of my app. If I add the name it will solve my problem?

Comment: @malcoauri yes definitely

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @meda points, I would say The ranking algorithm doesn't order the results only `by app names, it also includes app ratings, relevant keywords in your description ,number of downloads, Star rating, Speed of downloads vs release date` and probably some other stuff.

[Refer here for some more info](http://droid-blog.net/2012/03/07/app-store-optimization-aso-45-ratings-installs-or-the-google-play-search-algorithm/)